# Opengl-es draw an .obj file, but how?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I d like to parse an .obj file. My parser is working good, but my displaying is not good. 
Obj file is [here](http://pastebin.com/WKU9P1w2)

my code is:

```
    public ObjModelParser parse() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        InputStream fileIn    = resources.openRawResource(resourceID);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIn));
        String line="";

        Log.e("model loader", "Start parsing object " + resourceID);

        try {
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer parts = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
                int numTokens = parts.countTokens();
                if (numTokens == 0) continue;

                String part = parts.nextToken();

                if (part.equals(VERTEX)) {
                    Log.e("v ", line);

                    vertices.add(Float.parseFloat(parts.nextToken()));
                    vertices.add(Float.parseFloat(parts.nextToken()));
                    vertices.add(Float.parseFloat(parts.nextToken()));
....
```

and my displaying code is:

draw that model with `TRIANGLE_STRIP` and gl.`glDrawArrays(rendermode, 0, coords.length/dimension);`

[image]

What is the mistake here?

edited: [file here](http://pastebin.com/NbmyCZ2S) to show what is my good coords from my program for a cube, and what is from .obj file, that never show

Thanks, Leslie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to draw using TRIANGLE_STRIP instead of TRIANGLES, did you do the work and put the necessary degenerate triangles for STRIP to work ?

If you did put in those degenerate triangles I would bet a problem there, could we look at the  data output from your parser ? say just the first 10 triangles...

If you didn't create the degenerate triangles or don't know what that is just change the draw from TRIANGLE_STRIP to TRIANGLES, also using a triangle strip with a model like this limits some trick you can make with the normals, to produce better looking graphics. (if your going with simple or cartoony look ignore this part).

Comment: TRIANGLES and TRIANGLE_STRIP isnt work too. can you look at my codes here: http://pastebin.com/NbmyCZ2S ? thanks. My parser is working good. somehow the order isnt good.

Comment: But did you make your parsing code for TRIANGLES or TRIANGLE_TRIP ? Because the output is completely different.

Comment: Can you try drawing your model using this conversion ? http://pastebin.com/EAtCcc1J , I converted it with my modified obj2opengl.pl, the code to draw it is right at the top.

Comment: if I using triangles, with the cube.obj file, I get a cube but only the half page can see on each side. http://pastebin.com/ybbzHyg0 here is the cube obj file

Comment: your file is working! but what is the probleme with the original file?

Comment: ok, so get the original here, and check your code, or just change it http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/ , my version is not ready for prime time yet, basically I added interleaved vertex data and binary output.

Comment: The original file ? don't know you gave me a cube to analyze :-) give me the output from the first vertices of the actual camaro and it will be easier to compare :-)

Comment: can you show me more from the cube vertexes? because there is not good too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5308/discussion-between-led42-and-lacas)

Comment: oh, so the faces give me the order of my vertexes, vertex normals, and etc...? My parser isnt good then at the moment. :)